# Clojure: finding sequential items from a sequence

Tags: clojure, reduce

In a Clojure program, I have a sequence of numbers:

```
(2 3 4 6 8 1)
```

I want to find the longest sub-sequence where the items are sequential:

```
(2 3 4)
```

I am assuming that it will involve `(take-while ...)` or `(reduce ...)`.

Any ideas?

**Clarification**: I need the longest initial list of sequential items. Much easier, I'm sure. Thanks for the solutions to the more difficult problem I initially posed.

Comment: I should have qualified my question: the longest initial sequence. That probably makes the answer much simpler.

Comment: You should probably edit this into your question rather than leaving it as a comment, as this completely changes the game! Of course, for the same reason, it would be best if you made it clear that you've updated your question and what the original version was. (You've got some fine answer to that already!)

Comment: You're absolutely right. Will do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are only interested in the longest initial sequence, it's a 1-liner:

```
(defn longest-initial-sequence [[x :as s]]
  (take-while identity (map #(#{%1} %2) s (iterate inc x))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like APL without the funny unicode characters :-).

Answer (score 5):

Taking into account the OP's comment on the question -- which completely changes the game! -- this can be written very simply:

```
(let [doubletons (partition 2 1 [1 2 3 5 6])
      increment? (fn increment? [[x y]]
                   (== (inc x) y))]
  (cons (ffirst doubletons)
        (map second (take-while increment? doubletons))))

;; returns (1 2 3)
```

Note that this is actually lazy. I expect it not to hold onto the head of `doubletons` thanks to locals clearing. Another version:

```
(cons (first [1 2 3 5 6])
      (map second (take-while increment? (partition 2 1 [1 2 3 5 6]))))
```

The original version of the question is more fun, though! :-) A super-simple solution to that could be built using the above, but of course that would be significantly less performant than using `reduce`. I'll see if I have anything substantially different from zmila's and dnolen's solutions -- and yet still reasonably performant -- to add to that part of this thread later. (Not very likely, I guess.)

Answer (score 4):

Answer to original:

```
(defn conj-if-sequential
  ([] [])
  ([a] a)
  ([a b] (let [a (if (vector? a) a [a])]
           (if (= (inc (last a)) b)
             (conj a b)
             a))))

(reduce conj-if-sequential [2 3 4 6 8 1])
```

A more generic solution for those interested:

```
(defn sequential-seqs
  ([] [])
  ([a] a)
  ([a b] (let [n (last (last a))]
           (if (and n (= (inc n) b))
             (update-in a [(dec (count a))] conj b)
             (conj a [b])))))

(defn largest
  ([] nil)
  ([a] a)
  ([a b] (if (> (count b) (count a)) b a)))

(reduce largest (reduce sequential-seqs [] [2 3 4 6 8 1 4 5 6 7 8 9 13]))
```

I think this is much better.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to study your answer in more detail. I was trying to do something with loop/recur, but still have to think it through.

Comment: Hi David, I think you can replace the last line of largest with: (max-key count a b)

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn find-max-seq [lst]
  (let [[f & r] lst, 
        longest-seq (fn [a b] (if (> (count a) (count b)) a b)),
        [last-seq max-seq] (reduce 
                             (fn [ [[prev-num & _ :as cur-seq] max-seq] cur-num ]
                               (if (== (inc prev-num) cur-num) 
                                 [(conj cur-seq cur-num) max-seq]
                                 [(list cur-num) (longest-seq cur-seq max-seq)]
                                 ))
                             [(list f) ()]
                             r)]
    (reverse (longest-seq last-seq max-seq))))

(find-max-seq '(2 3 4 6 8 1))  ; ==> (2 3 4) 
(find-max-seq '(3 2 3 4 6 8 9 10 11)) ; ==> (8 9 10 11)
```